# How to take startDate and end Date from daterangepicker?

Tags: daterangepicker

var range= $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
autoUpdateInput: false,
locale: {
cancelLabel: 'Clear'
}
});

```
                   $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
                  });
                  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                      $(this).val('');
                  });

                });
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: Your question needs to be clarified and the layout improved.